# AWS lambda not able to trigger when parallel insertions of records were done in dynamodb

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, eventtrigger, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have set a trigger for dynamo db to a lambda function with default settings .
My problem is I have just wrote code to print the event in my lambda function whenever a new insertion is made.
I am creating 20 new items in parallel in dynamo db my lambda functions was not able to print event details for all the items inserted.Only 1 or 2 events are printed out of 20.
I need a solution for this why the lambda was not able to print the event details for all the 20 items when they are inserted in parallel.
I am not able to know whats the problem with the lambda .
I inserted 20 items sequentially with 1 second delay between item to item .I found the lambda logs for all the 20 events.
So please tell me where the problem occurs whether in dynamo db or lambda .Is there any configurations to change while setting the trigger other than default settings.

Please suggest me to resolve this,as I am new to lambda function and dynamo db.